# SD card damaged

Tags: root-access

My phone model is Micromax A77 operating system is 4.2.2 jelly bean.SD card company Sony. My phone shows that SD card is damage format it.I format it but not shows.I restart it I again shows to format it again not show SD card

Comment: Have you tried another card to be certain the slot is good and the phone can read it? Have you tried to fix the partition table on the card? (You'd have to do it with a PC/Mac/Linux program).

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if the SD card is recognisable with an other phone or computer, in case it is still not working this could mean that your SD card is spoiled. If it works in an other phone or computer, it could be a problem with your phone.